# Why am I getting conflicting columns error through the API but not in the UI report builder for the new 2024 SA360?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-sa360-api

I'm trying to pull data from the new Search Ads 360 API. I've done the necessary set up to where I can get data depending on the query I put together. The issue i'm facing is that for this specific query

```
SELECT
    segments.date,
    customer.account_type,
    campaign.id,
    campaign.name,
    ad_group.id,
    ad_group.name,
    ad_group_ad.ad.id,
    segments.conversion_action_name,
    segments.keyword.info.text,
    segments.keyword.info.match_type,
    metrics.all_conversions
FROM ad_group_ad
WHERE segments.date DURING YESTERDAY
```

I'm getting the following error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument. [type_url: "type.googleapis.com/google.ads.searchads360.v0.errors.SearchAds360Failure"
value: "\n\211\002\n\002(5\022\202\002Cannot select the following segments because at least one unsupported metric is found in SELECT or WHERE clause: \'segments.keyword.info.match_type\'(unsupported metrics: \'all_conversions\'), \'segments.keyword.info.text\'(unsupported metrics: \'all_conversions\').\022\0264VCNXxPgbOuRD-Pa0DDClg"
]
```

However, on the new SA360 UI, I'm able to pull those cols in together. This seems odd as usually api limitations would match what you can do in the UI.

[image]